# Pymodbus: write_coil also writes in discrete input register?

Tags: modbus, datastore, pymodbus, coil

I have a question regarding the pymodbus module and its functionality. My server works just fine, as well as the implemented datastore, I guess.

Here is the code for my server and datastore:

```py
import asyncio

from pymodbus.datastore import (ModbusSequentialDataBlock,ModbusServerContext,ModbusSlaveContext,)
from pymodbus.server import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.version import version

def run_full_sync_server():

print("Creating sequential Datastore.")
# Creating continuing Datablock without gaps.
datablock = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0]*20) # Initializing starting address and registers with value 0 each

print("Creating slave Context.")
# Creating one slave context. Allows the server to respond to slave context with its unit id.
slave_context = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di=datablock,                       # 'di' - Discrete Input Initializer
    co=datablock,                       # 'co' - Coils Initializer
    hr=datablock,                       # 'hr' - Holding Register Initializer
    ir=datablock,                       # 'ir' - Input Registers Initializer
    unit=1,                              # SlaveID
    zero_mode=False
)

print("Creating Server Identity.")
# Creates Server Information.
identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification(
    info_name={
        "VendorName": "XXX",
        "ProductCode": "ModbusKassow",
        "VendorUrl": "XXX",
        "ProductName": "Synchronous Py",
        "ModelName": "Pymodbus Server",
        "MajorMinorRevision": version.short(),
        }
)

print("Starting Server.")
server_context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=slave_context, single=True)
server = StartTcpServer(context=server_context, identity=identity, address=("0.0.0.0", 502))
#return server

if name == "main":
asyncio.create_task(run_full_sync_server())
```

I am working with spyder atm, therfore I need a seperate instance for asyncio to get the server running.

As for writing coils/registers, there are some functions given from the module, but whenever I use the function
`write_coil`
the exact values appear in my discrete inputs datastore (run the script two times).

```py
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('127.0.0.1', port=502)

discrete_inputs = client.read_discrete_inputs(0, 14)   # start reading from address 0 
discrete_inputs.setBit(3, 1)                       # set address 3 to value 1 
discrete_inputs.setBit(1,1)
print(discrete_inputs.getBit(0))
print(discrete_inputs.getBit(1))
print(discrete_inputs.bits[:])
print()

client.write_coil(10, True)
client.write_coil(12, True)
client.write_coil(15, True)
reading_coil = client.read_coils(0, 14)  # start reading from address 1
print(reading_coil.bits[:])
```

I thought that the discrete inputs and discrete coils were seperate datastores because they were initialized seperately?

Also, why does the
`discrete_inputs.bits[:]`
returns a list of only 16 bool values because in the server script I initialized the datastore with a list of 20 values?

Whenever I run the script twice, my coil values will appear in the discrete input datastore:

```py
[False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False]
```

I know that each register/coil can only store 16 bits, which corresponds to the list of 16 values I get from the read function.

I tried the code above and were expecting that the datastores were seperately.
Also I was assuming that maybe I am only writing in one register, because I get exactly 16bits returned.
If that's the case however, I do not know how to access the other coil addresses.

Edit: code formatting

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that the discrete inputs and discrete coils were separate datastores because they were initialized separately?

They are; but you are creating a single store and then assigning that same store to each element. Try something like (showing two ways of accomplishing this):

```py
datablock = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0]*20)
datablock2 = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0]*20)

slave_context = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di=datablock,                       # 'di' - Discrete Input Initializer
    co=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0]*20),  # 'co' - Coils Initializer
    hr=datablock2,                       # 'hr' - Holding Register Initializer
    ir=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0]*20),  # 'ir' - Input Registers Initializer
    unit=1,                              # SlaveID
    zero_mode=False
)
```

> I know that each register/coil can only store 16 bits, which corresponds to the list of 16 values I get from the read function.

I think you may be confusing the Modbus protocol and the PyModbus implementation. A Modbus coil is one bit (The PyModbus datastore may end up storing that one bit in a 16-bit variable but that is an implementation detail).

As per [the docs](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.html#pymodbus.bit_read_message.ReadCoilsResponse):

> The coils in the response message are packed as one coil per bit of the data field.
> Status is indicated as 1= ON and 0= OFF. The LSB of the first data byte contains the output addressed in the query. The other coils follow toward the high order end of this byte, and from low order to high order in subsequent bytes.
> If the returned output quantity is **not a multiple of eight**, the remaining bits in the final data byte will be padded with zeros (toward the high order end of the byte). The Byte Count field specifies the quantity of complete bytes of data.

You are requesting 14 registers (`client.read_discrete_inputs(0, 14)`) so the output will be rounded up to 2 bytes (16 bits).

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying my questions!

Comment: I almost thought that the datastores were mixed up. Now I created them seperately. And yes, I might have gotten the protocol and PyModbus implementation mixed up as well. Also another question did pop up by now: I tried to have a RaspberryPi read and write to the server (over TCP) that is running on my laptop, but it only lets me write to it. Do you have any clue why? IP addresses were in the same domain and I deactivated firewalls, so the communication can be established but it does not let me read the server from any external device.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was with the Windows Firewall.